# How connect a Xamarin.Forms Client to ASP.NET Core Identity (with Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity

I‘ve a ASP.Net Core Razor Pages project with ASP.Net Core Identity so it’s working with my own MSSQL DB specifically Entity Framework.
I’ve some CRUD things (some only for registered users).

So my question, how can I build a Xamarin.Forms Client that can use the same ASP.Net Core Identity implementation as my Razor Pages Project, for registration login/logout.
I can’t find a actual tutorial for ASP.Net 5?!

Furthermore a want use an external login beside my own DB, Facebook/Google etc.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the services of your web site inside a mobile app, you have to create an API with ASP.NET Core then you can use that API in your mobile app and also in your Razor web site.

For example if you have a page that shows a list of products in your Razor app, and you want to show that products inside your Xamarin app, you have to either embed your web site inside a WebView in your app or use an API from your ASP service to get the products and show them.

For authentication from a mobile app, you should either show a WebView and do authentication inside your web site and then copy the authentication cookie or use the proper approach and implement Token Based Authentication.

So search for these keywords: Token Based Authentication, JWT, OAuth, OpenId

External Authentication can easily be added to an ASP.NET Core app. Check  [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0) out for that.